# selenium doesn't set downloaddir in FirefoxProfile

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

i want to auto download files and save them in directory, everything is done but firefox stills save files in User download folder e.g. `C:\users\root\Downloads`

the function in class PyWebBot

```
@staticmethod
def FirefoxProfile(path, handlers):
    from selenium import webdriver

    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",1)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", path)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.downloadDir", path)
    profile.set_preference("browser.download.defaultFolder", path)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.alwaysAsk.force", False)
    profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", handlers)
    profile.set_preference("pdfjs.disabled", True)
    profile.update_preferences()

    return profile
```

then

```
 def setUp(self):
        self.profile = PyWebBot.FirefoxProfile(config['downloads'], config['handlers'])
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(self.profile)
    ...
    ...
```

config:

```
config['downloads'] = 'Q:/web2py_src/web2py/applications/internet2letter/private/testing/selenium/downloads'
config['handlers'] = 'application/pdf'
```

Comment: Try using  ` \\ ` instead of `/`. I had this problem a while ago.

Comment: didn't work :( i will try to use os.path.join

Comment: Are you sure it exists? It will be best to make sure in your script, something like `if os.path.exists` or `os.isfile`

Comment: nothing works, where do i find all options of set_preference ? maybe there are other options about the download folder, rather then downloaddir, dir, defaultfolder that should also be set ..

`>>> os.path.isfile(x)
False
>>> os.path.exists(x)
True
>>> x
'Q:\\web2py_src\\web2py\\applications\\internet2letter\\private\\testing\\seleni
um\\downloads'`

Comment: There is one other way that I can think to help you. When the firefox launches, go to `about:config`, find `browser.download.dir` and check if the value has been set. Another thing you are doing wrong, is `profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)`. It should be `2` not `1`.

Comment: it works, write that as answer so i will confirm it

Comment: Ok, added the answer.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are couple methods to a solution for this problem,

1. Make sure that the path is valid. Use something like, `os.path.exists` or `os.isfile`
2. When the `Firefox` launches with the selenium driver, navigate to `about:config` and check the look up `browser.download.dir`, to make sure there was a change.
3. Finally, make sure that `profile.set_preference` (`profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2`) has `2` as a second argument, since  `0` means to download to the desktop, `1` means to download to the default "Downloads" directory, `2` means to use the directory you specify in "browser.download.dir"
4. Make sure your path is noted with back slashes '\' not forward
   slashes '/'

Comment: This helped me! I also had to make sure my folder string was **backslashed** rather than forward slashed: `C:/Downloads` didn't work, but `C:\\Downloads` did.

Comment: The setting the folderlist to 2 was the key for me!