# How to download file using selenium?

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the download link and download the files.

I hava a log file which contains following links:

```
http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/18631-aida64
http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/4475-sumo
http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/2174-iolo_system_mechanic_professional
...
...
```

I have a code like this:

```
import urllib, time

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

f = open("dcrewtest.txt")

for line in f.readlines():
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[3]/div/a/img").click()
        time.sleep(8)
    except:
        pass 

     url = line.encode
     pageurl = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
     soup = BeautifulSoup(pageurl)
     for a in soup.select("h1#articleTitle"):
         print a.contents[0].strip()

     for b in soup.findAll("th"):
         if b.text == "Date Updated:":
            print b.parent.td.text
         elif b.text == "Developer:":
            print c.parent.td.text
```

Up till here I do not know how to get the download link and download it.
Is it possible to download the file using selenium?

Comment: possible duplicate of [downloading file using selenium](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/downloading-file-using-selenium)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html?highlight=profile#how-to-auto-save-files-using-custom-firefox-profile), you should configure `FirefoxProfile` to automatically download files with a specified content-type. Here's an example using your first URL in the txt file that saves the `exe` file in the current directory:

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver


fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

fp.set_preference("browser.download.folderList",2)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting",False)
fp.set_preference("browser.download.dir", os.getcwd())
fp.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-msdos-program")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get("http://www.downloadcrew.com/article/18631-aida64")

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='downloadLink']/a/img").click()
```

Note, that I've also simplified the xpath.

Comment: It works man.. I just manage to read all link from the txt file.. @alecxe

Comment: I tried, but how come all files are stored to /tmp/mozilla_[user]0/ with files end with `.part`