# Python 3.5 + Selenium Scrape. Is there anyway to select <a><a/> tags?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

So I'm very new to python and selenium. I'm writting an scraper to take some balances and download a txt file. So far I've managed to grab the account balances but downloading the txt files have proven to be a difficult task.
This is a sample of the html

```
<td>
 <div id="expoDato_msdd" class="dd noImprimible" style="width: 135px">
  <div id="expoDato_title123" class="ddTitle">
   <span id="expoDato_arrow" class="arrow" style="background-position: 0pt 0pt"></span>
   <span id="expoDato_titletext" class="textTitle">Exportar Datos</span>
  </div>
  <div id="expoDato_child" class="ddChild" style="width: 133px; z-index: 50">
   <a class="enabled" href="/CCOLEmpresasCartolaHistoricaWEB/exportarDatos.do;jsessionid=9817239879882871987129837882222R?tipoExportacion=txt">txt</a>
   <a class="enabled" href="/CCOLEmpresasCartolaHistoricaWEB/exportarDatos.do;jsessionid=9817239879882871987129837882222R?tipoExportacion=pdf">PDF</a>
   <a class="enabled" href="/CCOLEmpresasCartolaHistoricaWEB/exportarDatos.do;jsessionid=9817239879882871987129837882222R?tipoExportacion=excel">Excel</a>
   <a class="modal" href="#info_formatos">Información Formatos</a>
  </div>
 </div>
```

I need to click on the fisrt "a" class=enabled. But i just can't manage to get there by xpath, class or whatever really. Here is the last thing i tried.

```
#Descarga de Archivos
ddmenu2 = driver.find_element_by_id("expoDato_child")
ddmenu2.find_element_by_css_selector("txt").click()
```

This is more of the stuff i've already tryed

```
#TXT = driver.select
#TXT.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
#ddmenu2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[2]")
#Descarga = ddmenu2.find_element_by_visible_text("txt")
#Descarga.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Please i would apreciate your help.

Ps:English is not my native language, so i'm sorry for any confusion.

EDIT:

This was the approach that worked, I'll try your other suggetions to make a more neat code. Also it will only work if the mouse pointer is over the browser windows, it doesn't matter where.

```
ddmenu2a = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[1]").click()
ddmenu2b = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[2]")
ddmenu2c = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div/div/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td/div[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/div/div[2]/a[1]").click()
```

Pretty much brute force, but im getting to like python scripting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or simply use CSS to match on the `href`:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div#expoDato_child a.enabled[href*='txt']")
```

Comment: This one worked, much more efficient than the process i'm using.

Comment: excellent, glad to hear it helped :)  go ahead and click the green checkmark if this answered your question

Answer (score 0):

You can get all anchor elements like this:

```
a_list = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('a')
```

this will return a list of elements. you can click on each element:

```
for a in a_list:
    a.click()
    driver.back()
```

or try `xpath` for each anchor element:

```
a1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="enabled"][1]')
a2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="enabled"][2]')
a3 = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[@class="enabled"][3]')
```

Please let me know if this was helpful

Comment: What if there are 100 links on the page? He specified which link he wanted to click on and this does not answer that question.

Comment: Number of links doesn't matter: OP told that he need to click first one and question was "How to select <a> tags"! Try to clarify your downvote again or remove it

Comment: You need to reread the question. He didn't say the first `A` he said, `"a" class=enabled`. You grabbed *every* `A` on the page and started a loop clicking on them one at a time. What if an `A` leaves the current page? That's going to cause an error. If the click doesn't leave the page, that's also going to cause an error.

Comment: JeffC I think he meant, just go by every single step by Xpath. Like trigger the event by xpath, then move to dropdown menu by xpath and then click on the download link. Wich is the aproach i followed, and it works. But it will not work in loop if mouse is not over the web browser, wich is weird.

Answer (score 0):

you can directly reach the elements by xpath via text:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='expoDato_child' and contains(., 'txt')]").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='expoDato_child' and contains(., 'PDF')]").click()
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is a public link for the page in question that would be helpful.

However, generally, I can think of two methods for this:

If you can discover the direct link you can extract the link text and use pythons' urllib and download the file directly.

or

Use use Seleniums' click function and have it click on the link in the page.

A quick search resulted thusly: 
[downloading-file-using-selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/downloading-file-using-selenium)

Comment: Is a banking site, need to download some files, wich they will only send me in pdf format and need it to be in txt, wich are avaliable in their site. Also i found a work arround.