# Download an excel file from an html file in java

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm using Webdriver to perform all the UI actions. I want to download an excel file on Click operation of a WebElement. The below is the html code of the application.

```
<span class="excel ExcelLink" onclick="document.expForm.submit();">Download Excel</span>
```

I'm getting error has this WebElement doesn't have any 'href' attribute present in this. Hence I can't use the "HttpClient" to retrieve the file. how to download in this file in java / javascript?

Kindly suggest.

Comment: This form will change every time depending on some filters.

Comment: Java or Javascript?  Which one is it?

Comment: The html is calling a javascript on a click operation. I'm trying this either by java or javascript.

Comment: You understand that Java and Javascript are two completely different languages?

Comment: Yes I do understand, I have both the options to implement with.

Answer (score -2):

can u post full link to website? 
I think you are getting into this from wrong way. See that this element isnt anchor with href button but i suppose its form that redirects U to the file ( maybe file isn't on server just generated for download and than destroyed?). Have U tried executing onclick function??

```
 <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

@Luke Park, sorry for that, but i cant make only comments yet. I have to earn 50 points. Sorry if U not welcome with that. 
Here u have some code.

Python way:
[downloading file using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/downloading-file-using-selenium)

Comment: There is no button. In Selenium / WebDriver tool we call this has an WebElement. This is link which has a 'Form' associated. <form class="tokenRR" method="post" action="home.cfm?event=search.productsByName" name="expForm">

Comment: <form class="tokenRR" method="post" action="home.cfm?event=search.productsByName" name="expForm">

Comment: Don't post an answer unless it actually is an answer.