# python: How can I download data from the webpage where the link is hidden by the download button?

Tags: javascript, python, html, pandas, csv

Suppose I want to download data here: http://www.dce.com.cn/publicweb/quotesdata/memberDealPosiQuotes.html

When click the button shown below, I got a `.csv` file:
[image]

I want to do this automatically using python where I can specify the date etc.

I find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400867/pandas-read-csv-from-url) that one can use pandas `pd.read_csv` to read data from webpage, but first one need to get the right url. However in my case I don't know what the url is.

Besides, I also want to specify the date and the contract etc. myself.

Before asking, I actually tried to the dev tool, I still can't see the url, and I don't know how to make it programatic.

[image]

Comment: Use developer tools in your browser to get the url.

Comment: `javascript:exportData('excel')`, you can click on that button, programmatic.

Comment: @MrPyCharm see the edit.

Comment: @bhansa Can you be specific?

Comment: That could be achieved programmatically as @bhansa said. Selenium python bindings will do it for you. http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

Comment: @MrPyCharm How can I send a click not some text as in the example?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/downloading-file-using-selenium

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The javascript `exportData('excel')` results in a form that is submitted. By using Chrome devtools and the *Network* panel, you can figure out the headers and the post data used, and then write a python script to submit an identical http request.

```
import requests
url = 'http://www.dce.com.cn/publicweb/quotesdata/exportMemberDealPosiQuotesData.html'
formdata = {
    'memberDealPosiQuotes.variety':'a',
    'memberDealPosiQuotes.trade_type':0,
    'contract.contract_id':'all',
    'contract.variety_id':'a',
    'exportFlag':'excel',
}
response = requests.post(url, data=formdata)
filename = response.headers.get('Content-Disposition').split('=')[-1]
with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
    fp.write(response.content)
```

It's probably possible to find ways to modify the post data to fetch different data. Either by reverse engineering, by trial and error or by finding some documentation.

For example, you can include fields for year and date:

```
    'year':2017,
    'month':3,
    'day':20
```