# How to use selenium to save files found in links?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

In Python 3 I have this code with the use of selenium to automate a search on a site:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary

binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/lib/firefox/firefox')
ff = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)

ff.get('http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/diariojusticaeletronico/pesquisardiarioeletronico.asp#')

ff.find_element_by_id('argumento').send_keys('PPP')

ff.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/form/table/tbody/tr[3]/td/input[1]').click()
```

The code enters the [site](http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/diariojusticaeletronico/pesquisardiarioeletronico.asp#) and searches for the letters "PPP" on the "PESQUISAR" button

The result is a table with links to PDFs. The PDFs I want are in the "Integral" column

Please, is there a way to automatically save each PDF found in the links in the "Integral" column?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I download a file on a click event using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/how-can-i-download-a-file-on-a-click-event-using-selenium)

Comment: Thank you. With this question I was able to advance more in the solution, but still did not work. I'll post another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want you can use `requests`, i want to test, but i haven't permission on i try to open link, try this if you have permission, save all links that you need and after that use `requests`:

```
import requests
file_url = "http://www.stf.jus.br/portal/diariojusticaeletronico/verDiarioEletronico.asp?seq=14880745&data=23/05/2018&ano=2018&numero=101"

r = requests.get(file_url, stream = True)

with open("x.pdf","wb") as pdf:
    for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):

    # writing one chunk at a time to pdf file
    if chunk:
        pdf.write(chunk)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm not allowed. It's a government site, restricts access with requests