# Service Now CSV Export Redirection Python

Tags: python, csv, export, servicenow

I am currently working on a project and I have been stuck in exporting a table from the servicenow website using the code below, but is returning a URL redirection instead of the CSV.

Code:

```
url = "https://url.service-now.com/nav_to.do?" \
                    "uri=server_list.do?sysparm_query=active=false%26CSV"


response = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True, verify="C:\\Users\user\PycharmProjects\cert.crt")

LocalFilePath = "C:\\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Reporting\server.csv"


with open(LocalFilePath, 'wb') as csv2:
    csv2.write(response.content)
```

Any help and suggestion is much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `https://url.service-now.com` exists? For me it prints that domain doesn't exist.

Comment: Hi Andrej, The instance does exist and I replaced it with the word "url" for security purpose.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I notice is that your path information is not quite correct.

Wrong

```
verify="C:\\Users\user\PycharmProjects\cert.crt"
LocalFilePath = "C:\\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Reporting\server.csv"
```

It could be that \R is interpreted as a "carriage **r**eturn" (part of a line break): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-language/escape-sequences (I don't have Windows here right now.)

Corrected 1

```
verify="C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\cert.crt"
LocalFilePath = "C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\Projects\\Reporting\\server.csv"
```

Corrected 2 (recommended)

```
verify=r"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\cert.crt"
LocalFilePath = r"C:\Users\user\Documents\Projects\Reporting\server.csv"
```

Furthermore, you could try setting `allow_redirects` to `False` and output `response.is_redirect` or `response.is_permanent_redirect`.

Comment: Hi qräbnö, thank you for the help. That works perfectly.

Comment: Hi qräbnö, just a follow up on this. After about 5 times of executing the code, I am now getting a 302 http response and the csv file is empty. I have not made any other changes in the code other than modifying the allow_redirection to false. Just to add also, I am really a newbie in python

Comment: OK, set allow_redirects back to True. I just wanted to see if you get anything displayed at response.is_redirect (for debugging). If I could help you in any way, I would be happy about an upvote of my answer. ;)

Comment: Hi qräbnö, may i ask your suggestion on this?

Comment: Maybe use `import time; time.sleep(2)  # seconds` between requests? Then you might not get blocked so quickly. If you call the same URL with your browser, does everything work?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. If i browse the URL directly it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: You can probably use Selenium to download the CSV, but that might be a little too much of a good thing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/how-can-i-download-a-file-on-a-click-event-using-selenium

Comment: (Don't use PhantomJS or Firefox for Selenium. Use Chrome and chromedriver.)