# Can I use Python script to instead of chrome extension?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension

I used a chrome extension to download files on site, I want to know if I can create a Python Selenium script to do the same action like what in chrome extension? is it difficult?

Answer (score 0):

While this is **possible** it's *probably* not a great practice...
I am not that comfortable with <kbd>python</kbd> or <kbd>python-selenium</kbd>;

However I do understand that if it's a web driver then there probably is a way to get this accomplished, look around for <kbd>Python Selenium   file download API</kbd> on google.

Another aproach would be to make two apps that communicate with eachother - one made with `html`, `css`, `javascript`, `php`, *etc*   to find the name of a file on a webpage.

Then message this to python (once again not sure how to do this, it's ***probably*** on google somewhere) once the file name on the website and website name are passed to python then put them together with something like this (javascript variable joining in context example):

```
...
var example = pageurl_as_variable + "/" + file_name_as_variable;
some_download_function_defined_else-where(example);
...
```

then obviously download this as file...

Once again this isn't the best practice and you can't make a chrome extension with python due to security reasons, but as described in the example above you could make an <kbd>app-hybrid</kbd> and then run this on the target users computer.
There are a lot of ways to do this with just basic `HTML` and potentially `JavaScript` so your better off looking into a way to do it that way...

Here's some links to point you in the right direction:
  [How can I download a file from a link in HTML?](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_download.asp)
  [How can I download a file on a click event using selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/how-can-i-download-a-file-on-a-click-event-using-selenium)
  (couldn't find anything on passing messages between the apps in my 5-seconds of googling).