# Unable to click an element-Selenium python

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, automation

I want to download an image from Instagram
but I'm unable to click (using code) on the download button of [this](https://www.sssinstagram.com/p/B1cSJ8hlxXb/) page

I tried to click using XPath and CSS selector but it doesn't work.

`pyautogui.locateOnScreen('image.PNG')` does not work most of the times.

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath
elem('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a').click

driver.find_element_by_css_selector('body > div.page-wrapper > div:nth-child(5) > div > div > div.col-md-3 > div > div.button_div > a').click()
```

> NoSuchElementException

If there's any better way of performing this task please do let me know.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18439851/how-can-i-download-a-file-on-a-click-event-using-selenium you will get your solution here.(maybe)

Comment: Add [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits)

Comment: @Guy tried still didn't worked

Comment: @GovindSehrawat is you success to click the picture ?

Comment: @Frian check the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go, you don't need to click any button to download img. If you have the link you can you [urllib.request.urlretreive](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.urlretrieve) to download files.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import urllib.request

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless") # runs chrome in headless mode

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

driver.get('https://www.sssinstagram.com/p/B1cSJ8hlxXb/')

# To get the link via image displayed on the page use 
src = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/img').get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, src.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0]) # saves image with name 69346681_776681372728713_6952518582543886663_n.jpg obtained from the image url 

# to get the image via the href available on the page use 
href = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/a').get_attribute('href')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(href, href.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0])

driver.quit()
```

Comment: thank you so much for the help, can you also explain why it was not clickable

Comment: @GovindSehrawat I'm glad it helped.

Comment: @GovindSehrawat I was able to click the element. I used the same xpath as yours. Don't know exactly why it didn't work on your side. But for this case, you don't need to click image to get the image.

Comment: okay, can you suggest any tutorial or something for learning more about urllib library

Comment: @GovindSehrawat What happened ?

Comment: @GovindSehrawat Go through the official [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/urllib.request.html), it contains all the available methods and explanation