# Downloading images at a particular location in selenium python

Tags: python, image, selenium, web-scraping, data-science

I am trying to download images using selenium but I don't know how to direct those files at a desired location. Can anyone tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code to set desire download location in Selenium-Python bindings :

```
executable_path = r"C:\\Selenium+Python\\chromedriver.exe"
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {'download.default_directory' : '/path/to/dir'}
options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path, options=options)
```

You need to change `/path/to/dir` to your desired location.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using a Chrome webdriver you can use these settings:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument("download.default_directory=C:/Downloads")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Here I set it to "C:/Downloads" but you can change it to any other destination.
For the Firefox you can use this:

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
profile.set_preference("browser.download.dir", 'PATH TO DESKTOP')
profile.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/x-gzip")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
```

Where `'PATH TO DESKTOP'` is a path on your disk where you want to download your files

Answer (score 0):

as per this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18440478/8445072) to download using firefox

```py
from selenium import webdriver
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
path = 'C:\\downloads'
profile.set_preference('browser.download.folderList', 2) # custom location
profile.set_preference('browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting', False)
profile.set_preference('browser.download.dir', path)
profile.set_preference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'image/png', 'image/jpeg')
```

then select the button to download and click it.

if you only have the link of the image, i'd recommend using something like mechanize or urllib to download the contents

```py
img = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
src = img.get_attribute('src')

# download the image
req = urllib.urlopen(src)

f = open(filename,'wb')
f.write(req.read())
f.close()
```